# Find the odd integer (js fundamentals) - logic

Tags: javascript, arr

The task
Given an array of integers, find the one that appears an odd number of times.

There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times.

Examples
[0,1,0,1,0] should return 0, because it occurs 3 times (which is odd).
[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,2,2,1] should return 4, because it appears 1 time (which is odd).

I saw this solution but I struggle to understand the logic why it works:

e.g.

```
function findOdd(arr) {
  return arr.find((item) => arr.filter(el => el == item).length % 2)
}


console.log(findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5])) // returns 5
```

If the number must be odd, why it isn't ... `.length % 2 !== 0`;
I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Comment: In JS `0 == false` (Loosely equal) and a non-0 number is "truthy" (Treated as true in a boolean context)

Comment: it takes your array, then it filters it to only contain "the same", it then checks the length (times of occurrences) and checks whether that is a odd amount of time. All that is wrapped in `find()` which will only return once, the first time it validates `true`... So given the example array, find first validates whether 20 appears an odd number of times, - it does not, it then checks for 1, it then check for -1, then 2,,... etc. until it reaches 5, which validates to true, and `find()` then return that element of the array ;)

Answer (score 1):

`arr.filter(el => el == item).length % 2` returns 0 or 1. This is good enough, as that value will be coerced to boolean, and since 0 is falsy and 1 truthy, it has the intended effect.

Note that this algorithm has a O(n²) complexity. It is possible to do this more efficiently.

```js
function findOdd(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);
}

console.log(findOdd([20,1,-1,2,-2,3,3,5,5,1,2,4,20,4,-1,-2,5])) // returns 5
```

This uses XOR. All values in the array are XOR'd together. It is based on the consideration that `a ^ a == 0` for any value of `a`. And `a ^ 0 == a`. So if we have an odd number of `a`, we will get `a`, otherwise 0. As there is only one number whose occurrence is odd, we will find it this way. The special case of 0 will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Because [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#syntax) returns array which does contain items satisfying the condition. It returns filtered items, it does not "filter them out".

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and efficient solution

1. `arr.find((item)=>{}` this will loop through each items in the array and return the first satisfied value where we return true;
2. `arr.filter(el => el == item)` this will again loop through the same array and returns array of duplicate elements
   example if arr = [1,1,2,1,3] then `arr.filter(el => el == 1)` will return `[1,1,1]`;
3. `arr.filter(el => el == item).length % 2` this will return the reminder of result array of duplicate elements divide by 2, which should be 0 or 1
4. For javascript `0 == false` and `1 == true`; so when the find loop found a 1 from filter it will return the value;